# Using PDO with numbers versus strings

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following PHP code:

```
$comp1 = $_POST['cohort_id1'];
$comp2 = $_POST['cohort_id2'];
$comp3 = $_POST['cohort_id1'];
$comp4 = $_POST['cohort_id2'];

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT cat_code, value, :comp1 , :comp2, round(:comp3/:comp4 * 100) as index_number FROM {$table}";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY) );
$stmt->execute(array(':comp1' => $comp1, ':comp2' => $comp2, ':comp3' => $comp3, ':comp4' => $comp4 ));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Here is how one of the objects is returned:

```
?: "national_percent"
cat_code: "edu"
index_number: null
value: "Some College"
```

What I can't understand is why the first line returns with a "?", but more importantly, why the `index_number` is null. I suspect it is because those values are being converted into strings, but I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: To specify the types you bind before execute and do execute() with no params

Comment: @developerwjk Not sure I follow this, can you give an example?

Comment: See [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: so what are your `$comp1` and `$comp2`  values? do you have such columns in your table?\

Comment: Yes. I have these two values as columns in my table. If I run it like this (which is vulnerable to SQL injection), it works fine:
`$sql = "SELECT `cat_code`, `value`, `{$comp1}`,`{$comp2}`, round({$comp1}/ {$comp2} * 100) as index_number FROM {$table};";`

`$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Because you can't bind columns. `SELECT OK, OK, :comp1 , :comp2` last two, NOT OK. Nor this `round(:comp3/:comp4 * 100)`. Use variables. Here, have a read http://stackoverflow.com/q/182287/

Comment: I've asked WHAT VALUES are they?

Comment: @Alex Example values: national_percent, database_percent

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm with you. How do I ensure that I'm not ending up with SQL injection issues since these two variables come from user input?

Comment: TBH Jon, I don't know because I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it lol - If you haven't read the manual, have a look http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent SQL injection of user input that contains column names, check the input against an array of valid column names:

```
$valid_columns = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
if (in_array($user_input_col, $valid_columns)) 
{
  $sql = "SELECT {$user_input_col} from table...";
  ...
}
else
{
     die('Invalid column name');
}
```